# Пустое сообщение с формы обратной связи PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Прошу помощи, приходят сообщения, в которых только такое содержание:
Name:

Email:

Subject:

Message:

html

```
 <section id="contact-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">        
            <h2>Оставьте своё сообщение</h2>
            <p class="lead">123123123asfasdasdasdasd</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ваше имя *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Телефон</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Компания</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Тема *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Сообщение *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#contact-page-->
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Спасибо, что написали нам. '
);

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 


$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'pmymail@mail.mail';//replace with your email



$body = ('Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message);

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Такое ощущение, что выдран кусок из кода.
Попробуйте в самый верх файла вставить:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$mailheaders = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: name@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: ".$_POST['name']."<".$_POST['email'].">\n";
mail('vashemail@mail.com', $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
```

//exit; // %) проверяйте входящие данные

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема кроется в том что ваша форма контакта не имеет защиты от спам ботов, т.е любой спам бот который 'гуляет' по интернету, может спокойно использовать вашу форму для отправления спама.Вам надо (например) установить `Google recaptcha` в коде вашей формы для предотвращения несанкционированных отправок формы. Для примера можете прочитать [ТУТ](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2178)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST)){
$sendto   = "xxxxxxx@yandex.ru";//адрес куда должно прийти письмо
$username = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$usermail = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$useradvertising = htmlentities($_POST['advertising']);
$currDate = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
//$user = $_POST[''];

// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "письмо пришло с сайта-хххххх";
$headers  = "From:" . strip_tags($username) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Advertising:". strip_tags($useradvertising). "\r\n";
$headers .= "Date:". strip_tags($currDate). "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Заказ с landingPage</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Имя:</strong>".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Email:</strong>".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Тема:</strong>".$useradvertising."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Дата:</strong>".$currDate."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)){
//ответ отправителю
 echo "<p  style='margin-top:15%'><strong>".$username." ваш заказ принят,</strong></p>\r\n <p><strong>ответ будет отправлен,</strong></p>\r\n <p><strong>на адрес : ".$usermail."</strong></p>";
} else {
 echo "<p><strong>Приносим извинения.</strong></p>\r\n <p><strong>Произошел сбой системы.</strong></p>\r\n <p><strong>Попробуйте еще раз.</strong></p>";
}
};
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте  необходимые вам поля через  $user_xxx  и с богом..

Answer (score 0):

Защита тут не причём - это уже другой вопрос, сообщения должны приходить.
На сколько вижу вы передаёте json формат в шапке, попробуйте передавать текст в нужной кодировке

с

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

на

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```